# importing project into eclipse using bash script

Tags: 14.04, bash, eclipse

I am writing a bash script to install the eclipse neon on ubuntu 16.04. 
After installation, I want to import a project automatically. Once the eclipse begins, I should find the project inside project manager. Second time, when I open the eclipse, if the project should get refreshed/updated to  changes last time made in it. Any clue or reference to do it ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to run eclipse functions from the terminal, but if it really needs to be done by script, you could write a horribly-long and messy script which clicks gui buttons with `xdotool`

Comment: Maybe you can just copy the project folder into the workspace.

Comment: Is there any way to make the default workspace of eclipse to my desired folder using bash script, so that all the changes will be saved in the folder directly ?